# How to write java regular expression for decimal(x,x)

Tags: java, regex

In my java application the user provides some data_type as string. Now I have to validate that it is the appropriate data type or not. But for below data type there may be n number of possibilities:

1. `varchar(x)` where `x` is digit
2. `decimal(x,y)` where `x` and `y` are digits.

So how can I write a regular expression for that?

Comment: Each datatype will have different specification of sizes. You will have to list all datatype along with their specifications. So that list [like this can be used with alteration.](https://regex101.com/r/nJ4qH7/1)

Comment: Can you give example strings that a user could put and expected results? I would assume you would expect the following strings to work:
1    2,2    10    0,22    But anything with an alpha in would not. Is that correct, or would you accept more inputs?

Comment: i´d suggest to rather use a proper parser instead of trying to write a regex to achive the result.

Comment: We have a hard code list, and these are two type which can be dynamic. So need to place regular expression for these two  seperately . .

Comment: please, provide examples inside your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`varchar\(\d+\)|decimal\(\d+,\d+\)`